# Help choosing 64 bit based OS?

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, amd-graphics

I am writing to ask if my AMD Phenom 9550 Quad core processor will be able to run a 64bit flavor of Ubuntu Raring Ringtail.

Comment: 2nd link on google: http://openbenchmarking.org/s/AMD%20Phenom%209550

Comment: According to characteristics, it is nearly 128-bit CPU. So answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the AMD product sheet](http://products.amd.com/en-us/desktopcpudetail.aspx?id=400) (the *first* result on Google for `AMD Phenom 9550`):

> Operating Mode 64 Bit: Yes